# i want answer in horizontal loop with desire number of space in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tkinter, operating-system, tkinter-layout

#i dont know whts worng i want result in horizontal format with desire space between them

```
from tkinter import *
import os

window = Tk()
window.title("Window") #window dimensions
window.configure(bg = "black")
HEIGHT = window.winfo_screenheight()  #height and width
WIDTH = window.winfo_screenwidth()
RESOL = str(WIDTH) + "x" + str(HEIGHT+7) + "+" + str(-7) + "+" + str(0)
window.geometry(RESOL)

l = os.listdir("D:/anime")
l1 = l[0:5]         #five number of files
x = 0
y = 0
count = 0
for item in l1:     #its working well but it give result in vertical loop 
    Label(window, text = item, bg = "green").place(x = x, y = y)
    y += 30         #i want result in horizontal loop with desire number of space between
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a horizontal row of labels, it's much easier to use `pack` than place. `place` requires a lot more work and isn't responsive unless you do even more work to make it responsive.

Instead, create a frame for the labels and use `pack`:

```
label_frame = Frame(window)
label_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

for item in l1:
    label = Label(label_frame, text=item, bg="green")
    label.pack(side="left")
```

If you want to control the space between widgets, add some padding by either specifying a single value for `padx` which adds space to both sides, or just add space to the right of every widget using a 2-tuple. In the following example it adds 10 pixels to the right of every widget and 0 pixels to the left:

```
label.pack(side="left", padx=(0, 10))
```